# Search EWS CalendarItems with last modified time

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, last-modified

I'm searching for `CalendarItems` with Exchange Web Services. In the documentation on MSDN there is a field named `LastModifiedTime`.

How do I query `CalendarItems` by `LastModifiedTime` with Exchange Server Bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out a way with using restictions

(but by searching 
If findItemRequest object's
findItemRequest.Item 
findItemRequest.Restictions properties are defined
It gives combination error...)

If only Item  or Restictions  is defined for  findItemRequest object it works

```
        List<CalendarInfo> calendarEvents = new List<CalendarInfo>();

        ExchangeServiceBinding esb = EWS.Helper.ExchangeHelper.GetExchangeBinding(credentials);

        // Form the FindItem request.
        FindItemType findItemRequest = new FindItemType();


        CalendarViewType calendarView = new CalendarViewType();
        calendarView.StartDate = criteria.StartDateAndTime;
        calendarView.EndDate = criteria.EndDateAndTime;

        if (criteria.MaxItemsToReturn > 0)
        {
            calendarView.MaxEntriesReturned = criteria.MaxItemsToReturn;
            calendarView.MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = true;
        }

        findItemRequest.Item = calendarView;

        //--
        PathToExtendedFieldType sySyncProp = new PathToExtendedFieldType();



        sySyncProp.PropertyTag = "0x3008";
        sySyncProp.PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.SystemTime;
        // Define restrictions

        RestrictionType ffRestriction = new RestrictionType();
        IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType ieGreater = new IsGreaterThanOrEqualToType();

        ieGreater.FieldURIOrConstant =  new FieldURIOrConstantType();
        ieGreater.FieldURIOrConstant.Item = new ConstantValueType();
        (ieGreater.FieldURIOrConstant.Item as ConstantValueType).Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime().ToString("u");
        ieGreater.Item = sySyncProp;

        ffRestriction.Item = ieGreater;

       findItemRequest.Restriction = ffRestriction;

        //--
        // Define which item properties are returned in the response.
        ItemResponseShapeType itemProperties = new ItemResponseShapeType();

        // Use the Default shape for the response. 
        itemProperties.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties;
        //insert last modified time value also to responses
        PathToExtendedFieldType[] ptufta = new PathToExtendedFieldType[1];
        ptufta[0] = new PathToExtendedFieldType();
        ptufta[0].PropertyTag = "0x3008"; //Property Tag for LastModifiedTime 
        ptufta[0].PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.SystemTime;
        itemProperties.AdditionalProperties = ptufta;

        findItemRequest.ItemShape = itemProperties;

        DistinguishedFolderIdType[] folderIDArray = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[1];
        folderIDArray[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
        folderIDArray[0].Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.calendar;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.EmailAddress))
        {
            folderIDArray[0].Mailbox = new EmailAddressType();
            folderIDArray[0].Mailbox.EmailAddress = criteria.EmailAddress.Trim();
        }

        findItemRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray;

        // Define the traversal type.
        findItemRequest.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow;

        try
        {
            // Send the FindItem request and get the response.
            FindItemResponseType findItemResponse = esb.FindItem(findItemRequest);

            // Access the response message.
            ArrayOfResponseMessagesType responseMessages = findItemResponse.ResponseMessages;
            ResponseMessageType[] rmta = responseMessages.Items;

            int folderNumber = 0;

            foreach (ResponseMessageType rmt in rmta)
            {
                // One FindItemResponseMessageType per folder searched.
                FindItemResponseMessageType firmt = rmt as FindItemResponseMessageType;

                if (firmt.RootFolder == null)
                    continue;

                FindItemParentType fipt = firmt.RootFolder;
                object obj = fipt.Item;

                // FindItem contains an array of items.
                if (obj is ArrayOfRealItemsType)
                {
                    ArrayOfRealItemsType items = (obj as ArrayOfRealItemsType);
                    if (items.Items == null)
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine("Folder {0}: No items in folder", folderNumber);
                        folderNumber++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CalendarInfo ce;
                        CalendarItemType cal;
                        foreach (ItemType it in items.Items)
                        {

                            if (it is CalendarItemType)
                            {
                                cal = (CalendarItemType)it;
                                ce = GetCalendarInfo(esb, cal);
                                calendarEvents.Add(ce);
                            }
                            //Console.WriteLine("Folder {0}: Item identifier: {1}", folderNumber, it.ItemId.Id);

                        }

                        folderNumber++;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }


        return calendarEvents;
```